# Why my screen switched off a few times without any reason?

Tags: mac-mini, screen

I have new Mac mini for a few weeks. Lately I noticed something strange. From time to time, during regular usage (web browsing, reading PDFs, listening to music etc.) the screen turned black for a second or two and everything got back to normal state. Today for the first time the screen went totally dead. I got a snowy image, the one you get on an analog TV when no antenna is connected. However, the music I was listening to was still playing. I just put my Mac to sleep with the power button and woken it up. Everything is OK now, but I'm pretty concerned with this. What could it be?

Today I installed XQuartz but I don't think it could be the problem. The black screens appeared before the installation.

Comment: Have you tried a different data cable?

Comment: Nope, I don't have any other. Could that really be the problem?

Comment: Of course. If it doesn't work correctly or has a bad connection then it's entirely possible